# how to hide system() output

Tags: php, system

i am working on windows XP . i can successfully run a system() command through my browser by calling a TCL script that automates a ssh session. I also return a value from the script. however my problem is that the script dumps the entire ssh session in the browser.

my php script looks like :

```
$lastline=system('"C:\tcl\bin\tclsh.exe" \path to file\filename.tcl '.$username.' '.$pass,$val);
```

filename.tcl:

```
spawn plink -ssh $user@$host   
expect "password:"  
send "$pass\r"  
expect "\prompt:/->"   
set $return_value [string compare /..string../ $expect_out(buffer)]   
/...some code...this runs fine/  
exit $return_value
```

everything runs fine and i get $return_value back correctly but the php file prints the result of the execution of the entire ssh session in my browser which looks like:

> Using username "admin". admin@10.135.25.150's password: === /**some text**/ === \prompt:/->.../some text/

i want to prevent the system() function from printing this in my browser
i have used the shell_exec() function but it returns the entire ssh session result (which i have parsed in the tcl script and got a precise value to return to the php script)
is there a way i can do this without using shell_exec() but using system() instead

thanks in advance

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The [documentation for system()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) specifically says:

> Execute an external program and display the output

On that page are listed alternatives.  If you use [the exec function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead, it will only execute the commands without displaying any output.

Example:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, ";
system("ls -l");
echo "world!\n";
?>
```

will display the output of `system`:

```
$ php -q foo.php
Hello, total 1
-rw-r--r-- 1 bar domain users 59 Jul 15 16:10 foo.php
world!
```

while using `exec` will not display any output:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, ";
exec("ls -l");
echo "world!\n";
?>

$ php -q foo.php
Hello, world!
```

Comment: thanks csl ... it works ... earlier i was using ob_start() and ob_end_clean() functions before and after the system() command to get the desired results ... thanks for the input ....

Comment: Neither ob_start nor exec helped me prevent the stderr from showing. If someone wants this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171386/capture-supress-all-output-from-php-exec-including-stderr/33173998

Answer (score 4):

use ob_start(); before and ob_clean(); after calling it

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/850a3.php

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
echo '<pre>'; 
$last_line = system('ls'); 
ob_clean(); 
echo 'nothing returned!'; 
?>
```

Comment: sry for missing that out in my ques, but even when is do that $result stores the value of $return_value which i am passing back from the tcl script. nevertheless, output still dumps the ssh session in my browser

Answer (score 1):

In general if you want to prevent anything to output to the browser you can use ob_start() before your system() call and then ob_end_clean(). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php