# Codeigniter zip archive password

Tags: codeigniter, zip

I am using Zip helper from CodeIgniter to create archive. Everything works perfect, I want to add password for this zip, can anyone help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do this in Codeigniter or native PHP for that matter, you'll need to use the `system()` function and process the Zip on your host machine.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/646221/1734864 for a fuller answer and http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php for the function reference.

Comment: Thanks, maybe customizing Zip helper for codeigniter should do the work. I will give it a try and back to you.