# Download an excel sheet that is password protected in PHP?

Tags: php, phpexcel

Is there a way to download a spreadsheet that is password protected? I found libraries such as `PHPExel` but they do not work. Is there any other alternative?

```
if(isset($_POST["export_excel"]))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Datas ORDER BY ID DESC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    ....
    ....
    ....
    $output .= '</table>';
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; 
        filename= DB".date('Y_m_d').".xls");
        echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to password protect the spreadsheet the user downloads?

Comment: @NigelRen yes exactly

Comment: I've looked at various answers, which all seem to indicate that password protection is either to stop users changing the data or just not supported.  You may be able to protect it using a zip file - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47589645/1213708